# Android room database sometimes get null Application instance, sometimes it work

Tags: android, android-room, repository-pattern, android-livedata

I'm trying to create an instance of room database like this:

```
@Database(entities = [NotificationEntry::class], version = 1)
abstract class ApplicationDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun notificationEntryDao(): NotificationEntryDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: ApplicationDatabase? = null

        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(context: Context): ApplicationDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: createDatabase(context).also { INSTANCE = it }
            }
        }

        private fun createDatabase(context: Context): ApplicationDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                ApplicationDatabase::class.java, "roti.db"
            ).build()
        }
    }
}
```

And while initializing the repository:

```
private NotificationEntryRepository(Application application) {
        Lazy<ApplicationDatabase> databaseLazy = lazy(() -> ApplicationDatabase.getInstance(application));
        notificationEntryDao = databaseLazy.get().notificationEntryDao();
        notificationEntries = notificationEntryDao.getAll();
    }
```

And to describe the `getInstance` method:

```
public static synchronized NotificationEntryRepository getInstance(Application application) {
        if (application != null) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new NotificationEntryRepository(application);
            }
            return instance;
        }
        // right now this is based out of assumption that this `instance` will be available
        // and this `application` param will have `null`
        return instance;
    }
```

And calling it from vm like this:

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val notificationEntryRepository: NotificationEntryRepository = NotificationEntryRepository.getInstance(application)
    ...
```

But during debugging, I found that the `application` param is null. Thus it's causing the the repo instance to be null. And I can't enter data in this repository. But the funny thing is, sometimes it work.

Here does all my related deps:

```
    // room - database
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1"

    // rxjava - observer
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.16'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'


    // flow, livedata all together
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1"
```

What is the issue here? Can anyone help me figure it out?

Current source, to reproduce: https://github.com/maifeeulasad/notification-logger-android/tree/bc45bf1eb71c33c7c513dc897359bc016ae30dbb